# Failed to update data source credentials: The column 'budgetAmount' of the table wasn't found - Power BI Azure Cost Management Connector

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, cost-management

I started using the Azure Cost Management Connector for Power BI. I could use it without an issue on Power BI desktop and import data into my report. However, when I published the report, it gives me the following error:

[image]

My report is pretty basic. It only has [Azure Cost Management Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-azure-cost-management) as a data source. As far as the visuals go, I only have a simple table; no transformations, no customizations whatsoever.

But the problem is, I don't have any column named 'budgetAmount' any of my tables. I tried "Edit Credentials" option in the Dataset section of the report in Power BI report. It successfully logs me in but then throws this error. I'm only using the Usage Details from the Azure Cost Management connector.

Has anyone else faced a similar situation?

Comment: Hi Sahan, I am the engineer from the cost management team. Can you share your enrollement no. so that we can look at logs to see what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Hi @TusharJ Thanks for your comment. I have DM'd you on Twitter with the enrollment no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**02/24:** This issue is fixed and rolled out, make sure to install the latest PBI desktop from here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58494

[image]

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The issue happens because there is no budget available under the "**Cost Management -> Budget**". Until we get out a fix the workaround for now is to add a test budget in the azure portal and the report should start working.

**Steps to setup budget**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management/tutorial-acm-create-budgets

Comment: Thanks for the answer @TusharJ Don’t forget to update the answer once the fix has been deployed. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ywp I have same issue.  Its because the cost management plugin pulls data from a table called Budgets, which has an error.  You can bypass it in PowerBI desktop, but not if you want to schedule a data refresh in published power BI report.  You can see this by going to query editor and selecting source on the RHS, then select the budgets row.  There is no way I found to filter this row out before or during it reading data from the source.

Reference image:

[image: illustration]

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Collis. I will have a look and see if it solves my problem However, it seems like a bug from their side. Hope this gets fixed in the future